# restrict guest user to download any file

Tags: php, file, session, download

I have a page for downloading ppt file. I want to add one functionality, without providing login credentials, the page will not be downloaded. My code is like:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']) && basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'XYZ.ppt'){
    header('location:index.php');
}
```

But in the browser, if I type the full path of that ppt file, then it is not checking the session and automatically it is downloading.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restricting file downloads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210645/restricting-file-downloads)

Comment: I suspect you have already sent the header before you write the header again, turn up error reporting and see if there are any error messages

Answer (score 0):

In php, you can download like

```
<?php
// We'll be outputting a PDF
header('Content-type: application/pdf');

// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');

// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile('original.pdf');
?>
```